# Redirect file access for Windows desktop application

Tags: windows, file, redirect, process, samba

I have a simple Windows desktop application that stores all its files in one directory - exe, dlls, some databases and few configuration files.
I would like to be able to run it on every computer in the network via mounted samba share.

The only problem are those configuration files - they should be unique for each computer in the network and thus kept locally on every PC (some hardware related settings).

After the application launches from a share, is there any way, to force it to read/write few specific files from local disk instead of mounted share? It could be Windows 10 built-in tool or some 3rd party service/driver that will redirect file operations.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the application (launched from a share or locally) is run under the user's account, and inherits this user's environment. This includes environment variables like `%USERPROFILE%` or `%APPDATA%`. There is no need for any sort of redirection. The environment already is user specific.

Comment: Yes, but this application doesn't care about those variables. It looks for files in application directory (where exe is located) like in portable apps.

Comment: The only solution I can think of outside of installing the app on every machine would be to create a separate directory for each client, and use the Samba `%M` [variable substitution](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/smb.conf.5.html) to share them.  To save space you can set `allow insecure wide links = yes` in `smb.conf` and create each directory as nothing more than symlinks to the real files, except for the customized config files. Or you could make each separate directory a separate file system on something like ZFS that supports clones, then just modify the config files.